# Mysql for Excel UTF8 characters

Tags: mysql, excel, utf-8

Im using Mysql for Excel for editing my mysql db data. I need to put in czech special characters like ěščšřřýá, but it seems like the addon Mysql for Excel does not work with UTF 8.

When I update column with e.g.: "čř" its updated on "cr".

Does anybody have any experience? Im using this addon https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/edit/

Comment: Strange... It shouldn't even need a setting because both MySQL and Excel use a known encoding. Shall we assume that table collation is correct?

Comment: sure, the collation is set on utf8_czech_ci, which works fine for me..

Comment: What configuration are you using for MySQL?  How do you "update a column"?